# How can I set the position of a picture in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel 2013, elements such as slicers can have their location set via the properties side-panel, but the properties panel for pictures does not have position fields:

[image]

How can I set and change the position of a picture in an Excel spreadsheet precisely by entering the desired distance from the top and left of the workbook? Alternatively, how can I see position of a picture so that I can adjust it precisely?

The reason for this need is that I want to place pictures in the same position in multiple workbooks.

I have found several questions and answers related to achieving this via Visual Basic or macros, but I would prefer to use the Excel UI.

Comment: You can drag and move pictures. What else do you need?

Comment: I need to set the position explicitly, i.e. x cm from the top, y cm from the left, as can be done for slicers. It would be sufficient if I could see the absolute position of the picture, as I could then adjust it by dragging or moving. The reason for this need is to place pictures in the same locations in multiple workbooks.

Comment: @KendallLister Sidebar ► Picture tab ► Crop section ► *Crop position*: Change values for left and top. After this, in the section *Picture position*: Change values for X-Offset and Y-Offset back to 0. This way you can position any picture precisely

Comment: @nixda Thanks, that is unintuitive but it works! If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As nixda described, the technique is to use the Format Picture ► Crop panel:

[image: Excel Format Picture Crop panel]

First, adjust the *Left* and *Top* values to move the picture's outline to the desired position - you'll see the *Offset X* and *Offset Y* values changing in the opposite direction, and the picture will remain where it was and will be cropped by the moved outline, but don't worry about that yet:

[image: Excel Format Picture Crop panel adjusting the Left and Top position of a picture]

Now, change the *Offset X* and *Offset Y* values back to 0 to move the picture to the position of the outline:

[image: Excel Format Picture Crop panel resetting the Offset X and Offset Y of a picture to zero]